# Glue job is not able to read multiple files from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

Glue job is successfully writing the data from s3 to redshift table if i select single file but it's not when i select the folder with multiple files

I tried changing the script but it didn't work. What am I missing please let know.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Glue relies on Spark and is designed to process multiple files in parallel, so the issue is related to your usage. As mentioned, post a code snippet and the error code(s) you face.

Comment: you've had to provide the code that shows how you're currently reading single files and multiple files

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating your frame? Something like this should work

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    's3',
    {
        "paths": [
            's3://YOUR-FULL-BUCKET-ADDRESS/'
        ],
        "recurse" : True
    },
    "json",
    transformation_ctx = "df")

print('This is the total count:',df.count())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redshift spectrum, you can just query all the files in the s3 directory, turns them into a glue data catalog table